# Start and stop service

Tags: android, service

I have a code like this, which run, when click the button

```
if (isMyServiceRunning(PlayerService.class)) {
        stopService(mIntent);
        unbindService(serviceConnection);
    } else {
            startService(mIntent);
            bindService(mIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
```

When I click button and my service do not running, service start to work( all good here) 
When I click button and my service running, service stop and destroy( all good here) 
but when I click, to service start to work, service do not working

My Service

```
public class PlayerService extends Service {

private final IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return binder;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    doAnything();

    return START_STICKY;
}
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    PlayerService getService() {
        return PlayerService.this;
    }
}
```

}

Service Connection

```
    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {

        PlayerService.LocalBinder binder = (PlayerService.LocalBinder) service;
        myService = binder.getService();
        Log.d("TEST", "MainActivity onServiceConnected");
        bound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        Log.d("TEST", "MainActivity onServiceDisconnected");
        bound = false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Please check this https://developerlife.com/2017/07/10/android-o-n-and-below-component-lifecycles-and-background-tasks/

Comment: @Vadim :- what do u mean by this "but when I click, to service start to work, service do not working".Pls Ask properly your issues